# why can I fork without include a headfile

Tags: linux

```
int main()
{
    fork（）；
    return 0;
}
```

unistd.h hasn't included in this file, why can program still work just like I include a right head file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least `gcc` has a set of standard includes.
It's a toolchain-specific behaviour.
You should still `#include <unistd.h>` to make sure your code is portable.

Comment: But why gcc do this for us? I don't think that it is necessary.BTW, why is unistd.h in gcc's includes set ,but not the stdio.h?